# Access denied while Reading s3 bucket from Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am trying to read the json file from my s3 bucket using lambda function.

I am getting Access Denied with below error:

```
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): test-dev-cognito-settings-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com 
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied: ClientError
```

My Code snippet is below:

```
import boto3
import logging

def trigger_handler(event, context):
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj = s3.Object('test-dev-cognito-settings-us-west-2', 'test/map.json') // This line working
regions=obj.get()['Body'].read() // This line giving Access Denied :(

logger.info('received event: %s ',obj)

return event
```

My IAM role attached to the lambda function is below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Test",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:Get*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

IAM Role attached to the s3 bucket is below.

```
{
    "Sid": "AllowForSpecificLambda",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/lambda_allow_pretoken_generation_jdtest"
    },
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev-cognito-settings-us-west-2/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::test-dev-cognito-settings-us-west-2"
    ]
},
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Is that an IAM role / S3 bucket policy that is attached to your S3 bucket?

Comment: If your Lambda function has an allow s3:Get* policy on all S3 resources then your S3 bucket does not need a bucket policy that also allows access from that same Lambda function (at least for Get*).

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR it's an s3 bucket policy.

Comment: @jarmod in my s3 bucket's policy, I have few other restrictions as well. That I haven't mentioned.
But to allow my lambda function I have added this.

Comment: The stub you have shown should work without issues. There are 2 things here you need to ensure. 1. lambda_allow_pretoken_generation_jdtest is the IAM role attached to the lambda function. 2. Your bucket policy should not have a Deny that is not permitting your function to get the object.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR Thanks for the mentioned points. 
Point 1 is ok in my case.
Will check point 2 :)

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR You were right :)
The issue was with Deny statement. I added my IAM role which was attached to the lambda function inside my Deny->StringNotLike 
Solved!